# Why does my print method fail to print out the binary search tree inorder?

Tags: java, linked-list, tree, binary-search-tree

When I call print method in the main method, it prints nothing on the console.
I am trying to make a binary search tree in alphabetical order. Why is it that? Are my insert method and add method correct? Or, is it something wrong with the print method?

```
public class Node
{
    String value;
    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    Node(String val,Node left, Node right)
    {
        value = val;
        leftChild = left;
        rightChild = right;
    } 

    Node(String val)
    {
        value = val;
        leftChild = null;
        rightChild = null;

    }
}

public class binarySearchTree
{
    Node root;

    binarySearchTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public Node search(String element)
    {
        Node current = root;
        while (element.compareTo(current.value) != 0 )
        {
            if(current == null)
                return null;
            else
            {
                if(element.compareTo(current.value) < 0)
                {
                    current = current.leftChild;
                }
                else
                current = current.rightChild;
            }
        }
        return current;
    }

    public Node add(String element, Node bstree)
    { 

        if(bstree == null)
        {
            return new Node(element);
        }
        else if(element.compareTo(bstree.value) < 0)
        {
            bstree.leftChild = add(element, bstree.leftChild);
        }
        else
        {
            bstree.rightChild = add(element, bstree.rightChild);
        }

        return bstree;
    }

    public void insert(String element)
    {
        add(element,root);
    }


    public void print(Node bstree)
    {
        if(bstree != null)
        {
            print(bstree.leftChild);
            System.out.print(bstree.value + " ");
            print(bstree.rightChild);
        }
    }    
}     

public class testing
{
    public static void main(String[] agrs)
    {
        binarySearchTree tree = new binarySearchTree();
        tree.insert("apple");
        tree.insert("banana");
        tree.insert("kiwi");
        tree.print(tree.root);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accounting for the possibility that you might be adding to an empty tree, in which case you need to set the root node specifically:

```
public Node add(String element, Node bstree)
{ 
    if (root == null)
    {
        root = new Node(element);
        return root;
    }

    if (bstree == null)
    {
        return new Node(element);
    }
    else if (element.compareTo(bstree.value) < 0)
    {
        bstree.leftChild = add(element, bstree.leftChild);
    }
    else
    {
        bstree.rightChild = add(element, bstree.rightChild);
    }

    return bstree;
}
```

Comment: isn't it that my first if-statement already account for the possibility that the tree is empty? bstree is the root. When bstree is null, the tree is empty.

Comment: If the root of the entire tree is null, then you have to set root, which you later use to call the print method. The if statement that you currently have only checks if a given subtree's root is null, and in that you are only returning a new Node.

Comment: What do you mean by "set root"?

Comment: The root instance variable in the class `binarySearchTree`, it is never being set to anything except for null

Comment: Oh wait, the root is always null? I though the first top Node of a tree is a root.

Comment: Yes, but in your code, you are not setting it to anything

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is solution you need, but I know why you can't print all elements. Look at your contructor, you have created a BinaryTree with root element always is null. At the first time when you insert new element, function *Node add(String element, Node bstree)* was called and returned *new Node()* . Why you don't assign the new Node to current Btree because Btree still null  ?. We have a couple of solution to fix it. It's my opinion :

1. Create new contructor :

   public BinarySearchTree(Node root) {
       this.root = root;
   }
2. I change main function look like :

   BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(new Node("apple"));

P/s : I have created a BTree ( not the same your BTree) . You can see here :[BST-Level-Order-Traversal](https://github.com/tuyendev/30DaysOfCode/blob/master/Day-23-BST-Level-Order-Traversal/Solution.java)